# Count if a column has a specific value in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a column (user_id) with thousands of user_id (duplicated also), and another column (string) with several different strings. I would like to check if a unique user_id has a certain string and store the user id and 1 in a new dataframe. If the user_id does not have the string, then I would like to store the user_id and 0. In this case, I'd like to give a 1 to the string ¨good¨, and a 0 to any other string.

I can't seem to find a good way of doing so without looping endlessly.

INITIAL PANDAS DATAFRAME

| user_id | string |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | good |
| 1 | better |
| 1 | good |
| 2 | good |
| 2 | worse |
| 3 | worse |
| 3 | even worse |

DESIRED PANDAS DATAFRAME

| user_id | is string |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To keep it vectorized, we can skip the `apply`:

```
df['string'].eq('good').groupby(df['user_id']).any().astype(int).reset_index(name='is string')
```

```
   user_id  is string
0        1          1
1        2          1
2        3          0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could verify if the string is contained by using [issubset](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issubset.html):

```
res = df.groupby('user_id')['string'].apply(frozenset(['good']).issubset).reset_index()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   user_id  string
0        1    True
1        2    True
2        3   False
```

If need as integer:

```
res['string'] = res['string'].astype(int)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   user_id  string
0        1       1
1        2       1
2        3       0
```

As an alternative:

```
res = df.groupby('user_id')['string'].apply(lambda x: x.eq('good').any()).reset_index()
res['string'] = res['string'].astype(int)
print(res)
```

Comment: @Taco22 Glad I could help, but Erfan's solution is better.